# How to call a PHP function from a different page?

Tags: php

This is the USER class with the register and send_mail functions. The send_mail function doesn't work. I've followed other questions that were similar, but it doesn't work for me. Maybe someone can spot a mistake I've made, thanks.

```
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

class USER
{
    public function register($uname,$email,$upass,$code)
    {
        try
        {                           
            $password = md5($upass);
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userEmail,userPass,tokenCode) 
                                                         VALUES(:user_name, :user_mail, :user_pass, 
            :active_code)");
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_name",$uname);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_mail",$email);
            $stmt->bindparam(":user_pass",$password);
            $stmt->bindparam(":active_code",$code);
            $stmt->execute();   
            return $stmt;
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex)
        {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }

    function send_mail($email,$message,$subject)
    {                       
        require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsSMTP(); 
        $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 
        $mail->Host       = "mail.smeinfratech.co.za";      
        $mail->Port       = 465;             
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
        $mail->Username="datalogging@smeinfratech.co.za";  
        $mail->Password="**********";            
        $mail->SetFrom('datalogging@smeinfratech.co.za','SME DATALOGGING');
        $mail->AddReplyTo("datalogging@smeinfratech.co.za","SME DATALOGGING");
        $mail->Subject    = $subject;
        $mail->MsgHTML($message);
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Send();
    }
}
```

The following is the sign up page code where call these functions

```
<?php

  if(!session_id()){
    session_start();
  }

  require_once 'class.user.php';
  require_once 'dbconfig.php';

  $reg_user = new USER();

  if ($reg_user->is_logged_in() != "") {
    $reg_user->redirect('SystemStatus.php');
  }
```

Post for the submit button

```
  if (isset($_POST['btn-signup'])) {
    $uname = ($_POST['txtuname']);
    $email = ($_POST['txtemail']);
    $upass = ($_POST['txtpass']);
    $code  = md5(uniqid(rand()));

    $stmt = $reg_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userEmail=:email_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(
      ":email_id" => $email
    ));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
      $msg = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
                <strong>Sorry!</strong> The email already exists. Please try another one.
              </div>";
    } 
    else 
    {
        $reg_user->register($uname, $email, $upass, $code);

        $id  = $reg_user->lasdID();
        $key = base64_encode($id);
        $id  = $key;

        $message = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
                      Hello $uname,
                      <br /><br />
                      Welcome to SME Datalogging!<br/>
                      To complete your registration please click the following link<br/>
                      <br /><br />
                      <a href='http://elec.specmech.co.za/SMELogin2/verify.php?id=$id&code=$code'>Click HERE to Activate :)</a>
                      <br /><br />
                      Thanks,
                    </div>";

        $subject = "Confirm Registration";

        send_mail($email, $message, $subject);
        $msg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
                  <strong>Success!</strong>  We've sent an email to $email.
                  Please click on the confirmation link in the email to create your account.
                </div>";

      }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SME DATALOGGING | Sign Up</title>
    <?php require_once 'v2/php/head.php'; ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content" class="container pt-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
          <div class="system-card">
            <img src="v2/img/sme.png" alt="SME" width="100%"/>
            <form>
              <div class="text-center">
                <h4 class="mb-5 mt-5 text-primary"><strong>Sign Up</strong></h4>
              </div>

              <div class=" form-sm mt-5">
                <label class="required">Username</label>
                <input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" formControlName="username" name="txtuname" required>
              </div>

              <div class=" form-sm">
                <label class="required">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email" name="txtemail" required>
              </div>

              <div class=" form-sm">
                <label class="required">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" formControlName="password" name="txtpass" required>
              </div>

              <div class="row d-flex align-items-center mb-4 mt-4">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="btn-signup">SIGN UP</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="text-center">
                    <small>
                      Already have an acount? <a href="index.php">Sign In</a>
                    </small>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <?php
                if (isset($msg)) echo $msg;
              ?>

            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="vendors/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain the "doesn't work" part? Does it generate an error? Does the email not get sent or does it not arrive? How have you tested this?

Comment: @KIKO Software The email just doesn't send. I've tested the email function on another page inside a javascript function and then it sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see you are trying to call the send_mail method of the USER class as a regular function.

```
    $subject = "Confirm Registration";

    send_mail($email, $message, $subject);
```

This is not going to work, because there is no function named `send_mail`. 
You will have to create an instance of the class USER, and then call the method `send_mail`.

```
$subject = "Confirm Registration";
$user = new USER;
$user->send_mail($email, $message, $subject);
```

This is how you would call this method.

Or just like this (given that `$reg_user` is an instance of the USER class).

```
$subject = "Confirm Registration";
$reg_user->send_mail($email, $message, $subject);
```